# Pinax CSS suddenly stopped working and now black bar is gone but links still there

Tags: css, virtualenv, pinax

I am hosting Pinax on a virtualenv.

Everything was going great.  I started working on other pages in the virtual templates folder, adding CSS to it.

I reloaded the page and the black bar on top is gone!! The links are still there but the bar is gone.  I did not touch the PINAX original files at all.

The last time this happened, I cleared my cache and it was okay again.  I did that this time but it still isn't working.

I started a new server, installed a fresh new Pinax installation and Starter project.  Loaded that one..and the black bar is still not there.  CSS is still not being picked up.

I don't know what to do! I am using Firefox and then I used IE -- same results

Comment: Don't you have a backup of the original CSS? If you have one, make a copy but with a different filename, i.e. `styles.06202012.1835.css`, modify the pages with this new style and reload your page. Everytime you do a modification of your css, rename it, so that caching problems won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

If you are using Pinax, Pinax uses old bootstrap theme

You have to upgrade your twitter bootstrap and everything will be fine